# R - Removing a column in a dataframe, if the column values are the same as another column

Tags: r

I've inserted a table to make it clearer, basically, I'm trying to find a way to get rid of other columns that are identical in the values it has to another one, a duplicate column. 
[image]

As we can see in the image, Col 2 and 4 are identical, I want to remove Col 4, because for my use it's not helping and is unneeded data.

Thanks!

Comment: try `df1[!duplicated(t(df1))]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `duplicated` on the transpose of the dataset to create a logical index and use that to subset the columns

```
df1[!duplicated(t(df1))]
#    Col1 Col2 Col3 Col5
#1    1    2    3    1
#2    2    3    4    2
#3    3    4    1    4
#4    4    1    2    3
```